# shorter way to pause a video if it is fully out of view

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I have this code to pause a video if it is fully out of view
it works, but I want to make it shorter
for example, to avoid  `forEach` loop, because this is the only video on page
also - maybe to avoid a separate `modify` function - but place `el.pause()` inside the first block of js code
I tried on various ways and getting various errors in console
pls help

```
<video id='vsingle' src='lorem.mp4' poster='lorem.jpg' controls></video>   

let io = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if(!entry.isIntersecting){modify(entry.target);}
  });
});

function modify(el){el.pause();}

$(document).ready(function(){
  io.observe(document.querySelector('#vsingle'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify this code a little by removing the `modify` function:

```
let io = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if(!entry.isIntersecting){
      entry.target.pause()
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: it works, thanks. What about `forEach` ?

Comment: the API returns a list of entries, so you can't really change that.